# How to assign null to a hive table column using pyspark

Tags: dataframe, pyspark, null

My pyspark script is populating a hive table and one column need to be initialized as null so that the consuming code can check when(df.columname.isNull()) during select statement,
please advise how to set column name to null when writing to the hive table.

Comment: PLease provide more information

Comment: I have hive table and one column in the hive table need to be initialized with null value.  How to achieve that using pyspark ?

Answer (score 0):

lit(None).alias(Column_name) will give the result
Inside hive or beeline Column_name is null will return true